# Looking for a JS library to move text

Tags: javascript, text

I'm looking for a javascript library that will allow me to drag text over an image with some resize handles that will automatically wrap the text.

I've tried doing some searches but don't think I'm using the right search terms.

I'm hoping someone has come accross simliar functionality before.

Thanks :)

Comment: jQuery, Prototype provide drag & drop functionalities. You can write text in a DIV and drag it over an image. But finding a library which can resize and wrap text is the hardest part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the keyword you're looking for is "morph". Most JavaScript animation libraries have element morphing functions that change css attributes of an element in a given time.

You should check out the demos these libraries have and try to imagine how you can make them to fit your case.

Script.aculo.us provides one of the smoothest animations I've ever seen. You can check the List morph demo here:
http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/list-morph-demo
And for Effect.morph documentation here:
http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-morph

$fx is another beautifully crafted library just for animation:
http://fx.inetcat.com/manuals.php#b3

JSAnim is another good one:
http://jsanim.com/

Also check out animator.js:
http://berniecode.com/writing/animator.html

These are one of the most decent animation libraries. You'll realize there's a common pattern where you can combine the basic effects and functions to create any custom effect you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify your needs? Should the text get integrated in the image or should it only put over the image?

If you look for the second one, I would say, that you don't need any library. It should be possible with some lines of plain javascript.

Comment: The text doesn't need to be integrated into the image, just hover over it, select a font and wrap if the user clicks the resize handles.

I could write something but I'm in a lazy mood tonight :-)